# How to use mysql alias with php objects?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, alias

I've looked all over the SOF and google, I can't seem to find what I need (possibly, I'm using wrong keywords when searching.)

I'm trying to use this SQL:

```
SELECT c.*, d.*, img.*
FROM cars c 
LEFT JOIN dealership d ON c.d_id = d.d_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT min(id), car_id, link, thumb FROM car_images) AS img ON c.car_id = img.car_id 
WHERE c.status = 1 AND car_make = 'Acura'
```

the result i get:

```
car_id | d_id | car_make | status | d_id | dealer_name | car_id | link | thumb | 

   1       2      Acura       1       2        AAA        NULL    NULL    NULL   
   2       3      Acura       1       3        BBB        NULL    NULL    NULL   
   3       4      Acura       1       4        CCC        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Car_id #3 has image links and thumbs. When I try to use img.link or c.car_id it's null, because I use alias in my select. So I also tried to pull alias, such as `$car_rows[car]->img.link`(I use smarty, pass php object to smarty variable and use foreach to loop through it), but it throws error: 
`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$img in`

What should I do? I would like to return following columns: car_id, d_id, car_make, status, dealer_name, link, thumb

Comment: 1. Name all the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: I would like to return distinct value of all columns listed:car_id,d_id,car_make,status,dealer_name,link,thumb

Comment: I mean name them in your actual query... SELECT c.car_id, c.car_make...

Comment: I tried that, if I do that, when I try to get the var, it throws the `Undefined property: stdClass...`

Comment: If *you* do that, then *we* can begin to understand the problem

Comment: In general, `SELECT *` is a bad idea.  Name the columns you want to have returned, both for the sake of readability and clarity, and to potentially make the database do less work.

Comment: Thank you, sounds like I need to start changing a lot of my code, to select specific columns. Good advice. I figured out the answer to my question :) I just grouped by car_id. Thanks for all your help. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough on my question